# unwanted code hints (prettify.css) in vscode

Tags: text-editors, autocomplete, visual-studio-code, intellisense

where are these coming from
I have disabled all extensions. I am pretty sure that there is no `prettify.css` or `base.css` among my project files and yet I am still getting these code hints. How can I get rid of them?

- Unwanted code hints from `prettify.css` or `base.css` in VScode:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I forgot about node modules.

All I had to do was creating jsconfig.json file and adding unwanted paths to configuration.

It is all there in the documentation: https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/languages/javascript#_javascript-projects-jsconfigjson

*In my defense: node_modules was already added to watcher and search:exclude*